# Error "bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.readPemObject()" is null on flyway with snowflake

Tags: java, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, bouncycastle, flyway

I have a certificate generated in the following way:

```
openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -v2 aes256 -inform PEM -out rsa_key.p8
```

and I'm trying to connect to snowflake to run an info command on Flyway(sensitive information stripped out):

```
package com.example.snowflake_key;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationInfo;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationInfoService;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.MigrationVersion;
import org.flywaydb.core.api.configuration.FluentConfiguration;
import org.flywaydb.core.internal.info.MigrationInfoDumper;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Properties;

@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class SnowflakeKeyApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    Flyway flyway;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SnowflakeKeyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {            

        FluentConfiguration flywayConfig = Flyway.configure();

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("flyway.baselineOnMigrate", "true");
        props.put("flyway.outOfOrder", "true");
        props.put("flyway.table", "FLYWAY_SCHEMA_HISTORY");
        props.put("flyway.locations", "/db/scripts");
        props.put("driver", "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
        flywayConfig.configuration(props);

//        https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/snowflake
//        URL format    jdbc:snowflake://account.snowflakecomputing.com/?db=database&warehouse=warehouse&role=role (optionally &schema=schema to specify current schema)

        flywayConfig.dataSource("jdbc:snowflake://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com/"
                        + "?db="
                        + "&warehouse="
                        + "&role="
                        + "&authenticator="
                        + "&private_key_file=D:/Projects/Java/snowflake_key/src/main/resources/rsa_key.p8"
                        + "&PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PWD="
                , "some_user"
                , "some_password"
        );
        flywayConfig.schemas("some schema");
        flyway = flywayConfig.load();

        runInfo();

    }
         
    public void runInfo() {
        MigrationInfoService info = flyway.info();
        MigrationInfo current = info.current();
        MigrationVersion currentSchemaVersion = current == null ? MigrationVersion.EMPTY : current.getVersion();

        MigrationVersion schemaVersionToOutput = currentSchemaVersion == null ? MigrationVersion.EMPTY : currentSchemaVersion;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        buffer.append("Schema version: ")
                .append(schemaVersionToOutput).append("\n")
                .append(MigrationInfoDumper.dumpToAsciiTable(info.all()));

        log.info(buffer.toString());
    }
}
```

maven dependencies:

```
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.snowflake</groupId>
        <artifactId>snowflake-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.13.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

using liberica 17 JVM.

but I'm facing the following error:

> Private key provided is invalid or not supported:
> D:/Projects/Java/snowflake_key/src/main/resources/rsa_key.p8: Cannot
> invoke
> "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()"
> because the return value of
> "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.readPemObject()"
> is null

stacktrace:

```
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database (jdbc:snowflake://.....snowflakecomputing.com/?db=....&warehouse=....&role=....&authenticator=.....&private_key_file=D:/Projects/Java/snowflake_key/src/main/resources/rsa_key.p8&PRIVATE_KEY_FILE_PWD=....) for user '....': Private key provided is invalid or not supported: D:/Projects/Java/snowflake_key/src/main/resources/rsa_key.p8: Cannot invoke "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()" because the return value of "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.readPemObject()" is null
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 42601
Error Code : 200045
Message    : Private key provided is invalid or not supported: D:/Projects/Java/snowflake_key/src/main/resources/rsa_key.p8: Cannot invoke "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()" because the return value of "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.readPemObject()" is null

    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:67) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcConnectionFactory.<init>(JdbcConnectionFactory.java:74) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.FlywayExecutor.execute(FlywayExecutor.java:143) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.Flyway.info(Flyway.java:191) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    at com.hackathon.FlywayService.runInfo(FlywayService.java:72) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.hackathon.SnowFlakeMigrationService.lambda$processSnowFlakeMigrations$0(SnowFlakeMigrationService.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLLoggedException: Private key provided is invalid or not supported: D:/Projects/Java/ia-ds-snfl-load/service/src/main/resources/snowflake.p8: Cannot invoke "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject.getContent()" because the return value of "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.internal.org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader.readPemObject()" is null
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initialize(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:109) ~[snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar:3.13.25]
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.DefaultSFConnectionHandler.initializeConnection(DefaultSFConnectionHandler.java:79) ~[snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar:3.13.25]
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.initConnectionWithImpl(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:116) ~[snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar:3.13.25]
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeConnectionV1.<init>(SnowflakeConnectionV1.java:96) ~[snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar:3.13.25]
    at net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver.connect(SnowflakeDriver.java:176) ~[snowflake-jdbc-3.13.25.jar:3.13.25]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverDataSource.java:259) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:223) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    at org.flywaydb.core.internal.jdbc.JdbcUtils.openConnection(JdbcUtils.java:52) ~[flyway-core-8.0.5.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to generate a key using a different algorithm? E.g. ```openssl genrsa 2048 | openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -v1 PBE-MD5-DES -out test_rsa_key.p8```

Comment: I would suggest you install locally [SnowSQL](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowsql) and try logging in using same private key file and password. If that is successful, then at least you know the generated private key is good. If that fails then you will need to generate a new key maybe using a diffeerent algorithm as pointed out by @aek.